Change "Media" Title in rtMedia Plugin for BuddyPress to "Photos"
I'd like it to say "Photos" instead of "Media" on the nav item bar in buddypress. See this screenshot. https://ibb.co/BHJ86Fr.
In the code below "Media" changes to "Photo" when you click it. I need it to say "Photos" upon render.
// Change "Media" to "Photos"
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'is_rtmedia_bp_profile' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! is_rtmedia_bp_profile() ) {
        return;
    }

    ?>
    <script>
        if ( 'undefined' !== typeof jQuery ) {
            var photoElem = jQuery( '#user-media' );
                photoElem.text( 'Photos' );


        }
    </script>
    <?php
} );


That JavaScript in itself is not dependent on a click. So I can only assume that after the new page loads, your PHP conditions there make it output that script element for the first time - and that it wasn't even present in the source code on the previous page.

I guess you don't have to check if jQuery is defined as you are in the wp context.
If the menu as the unique id 'user-media', the text should be replaced with this code.
// Change "Media" to "Photos"
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () {
?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var photoElem = $( '#user-media' );
    photoElem.text( 'Photos' );
 });
 </script>
 <?php
} );


Thanks for this - unfortunately getting the same result #user-media is the id of the anchor tag which says "Media", which is wrapped in a li. Upon render it says "Media" then switches to Photos when you click it. When you refresh again it goes back to "Media"

What is is_rtmedia_bp_profile()? Should it mean this function is only fired on a specific page? I remove it from my answer. Perhaps it will solve your problem.

legend - thanks a bunch.
